# Socket ssh connections remotely?

Tags: python, sockets, ip, remote-server, portforwarding

I wonder and i've been trying everything to get my program with python sockets to work remotely. When I say remotely is like, I run the server in my computer and my friend at his house can run the client and connect to my server. Is this possible without using Hamachi? Pls let me know, because I'm already dying by trying so many things and installing and uninstalling programs.

Answer (score 0):

You have to activate port forwarding on your router so that everything that comes on the specific port is forwarded to your local IP (and the port should be open).

Comment: i've opened the port but i can't figure out how to activate port forwarding

Comment: Try Googling: "Port Forwarding {your router}".You should have admin access to it.